# Custom SQL response (JOIN TABLE)

Tags: sql, database, join, group-by, pivot

I have two tables, `table1` and `table2`

I want to link the two tables with the `id`, by grouping the information in one and the same answer.

**table1**:

```
╔════╦══════════════╦
║ id ║  product_id  ║
╠════╬══════════════╬
║  1 ║      123     ║
║  2 ║      456     ║
║  3 ║      789     ║
╚════╩══════════════╩
```

**table2**:

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦
║ id ║    status    ║     date     ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬
║  1 ║   received   ║    02/20     ║
║  1 ║   shipped    ║    03/20     ║
║  2 ║   received   ║    04/20     ║
║  2 ║   shipped    ║    05/20     ║
║  3 ║   received   ║    06/20     ║
║  3 ║   shipped    ║    07/20     ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩
```

I want this output:

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦
║ id ║    r_date    ║   s_date     ║  product_id  ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬
║  1 ║     02/20    ║    03/20     ║     123      ║
║  2 ║     04/20    ║    05/20     ║     456      ║
║  3 ║     06/20    ║    07/20     ║     789      ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩
```

How Can i have this result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two `LEFT JOIN`s, as in:

```
select
  a.id,
  r.date as r_date,
  s.date as s_date,
  a.product_id
from table1 a
left join table2 r on r.id = a.id and r.status = 'received'
left join table2 s on s.id = a.id and s.status = 'shipped'
```

Comment: Thanks you very mush! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do conditional aggregation to pivot `table2` over `table1`:

```
select 
    t1.id, 
    max(case when t2.status = 'received' then t2.date end) r_date,
    max(case when t2.status = 'shipped' then t2.date end) s_date,
    t1.product_id
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t.id = t2.id
group by t1.id, t2.product_id
order by t1.id
```

Comment: is the max() required though since in theory its only one date for each id?

Comment: @Travis: that's the principle of conditional aggregation. We need to wrap the conditional expression in an aggregate function in order to collapse the rows. It can be `min()`, `max()`, it doesn't really matter.